# How can select item from drop-down menu in cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, automated-tests, cypress

I have two questions.
First, the main one is how do I select one specific entry from the drop-down menu? For example test:

[image: Drop down menu]

And the code:

[image: DOM objects]

The second question concerns a tutorial that would explain to me how to search for and assign DOM objects to test them. I'm a little lost in it ...

And this is the code for do it better select:

[image: Code for better select]

Answer (score 1):

To select an item from a drop down menu in Cypress you need `select()`

e.g.

```js
cy.get('#ID_of_drop_down_menu').select('test')
```

In your case you could try

```js
cy.get('#dx-0d913c9b-e881-238a-e7ba-4254647fb326').select('test')
```

or via class:

```js
cy.get('.dx-scrollview.dx-visibility-change-handler.dx-_ical').select('test')
```

{edit}Could you possibly expand the HTML so I can see what selector you could use for the drop down menu.

{edit2}About your 2nd question: A good "training tool" is Selenium IDE recorder. You can record clicks on a website and it will show you the CSS selector it has chosen to address the element you clicked on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I put the other picture with code. I hope that help you.

Comment: Expanded my answer.

Comment: ok, thank you for help me and answer.

Comment: But what I can do, if  id= dx-0d913c9b-e881-238a-e7ba-4254647fb326 is changed by everytime...

Comment: Yeah, I was already afraid that this is a dynamic id. Try ```cy.get('.dx-scrollview.dx-visibility-change-handler.dx-_ical')```